# Insert from existing table into new table with ID added

Tags: sql, t-sql

I imported data from an Excel spreadsheet into a table, now I need to convert some of this data and then insert it into another table.  Everything in both tables will be the same except some `VARCHAR` will be changed to `BIT` type and the new table will have an `ID` field.

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, CASE Column3 WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Column3'
FROM MyTable
```

What I need to do is take all of that data and insert it into a new table that will have an ID column on top of everything in the original table.  What I am having trouble with is the insert statement, I know I can `INSERT INTO` then run a select statement and it will insert it, but I'm having trouble adding the `ID` field which should auto increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to be using the new table later, then you want to create it with an id column:

```
create table NewTable (
    NewTableId int not null identity(1, 1),
    <your columns here>
)
```

Then to insert:

```
insert into NewTableId(<your columns here>)
    select <your columns here>
    from StagingTable
```

This also gives you the opportunity to optimize the types of the columns.

If you just want an incremental number for the first insert:

```
select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as NewTableId,
       t.*
into NewTable
from t
```

I have found that using a constant expression in the `order by` runs faster than using a column name.  The performance benefit is strictly empirical, and not guaranteed by Microsoft.  However, it has worked for me in practice.

Comment: all basically said the same thing, you you explained things thoroughly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you could use:

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Column1)`

in your `select`

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
 Insert into YourTableName(Column1,Column2,Column3) (SELECT Column1, Column2, CASE Column3 WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'Column3'
    FROM MyTable)
```

Set your id field to identity field